# Solution of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Find all $(a, b)$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{ax-1+e^{bx}}{x^2}\right)=1.$ I figured that $a=-b$, but can't solve the values.

Comment: Just because there are a lot of people asking to solve calculus problems without L'Hopital's... is L'Hopital's ok?

Comment: Yeah, L'Hopital is fine.

Comment: Use the power series for $e^{bx}$. Or else use L'Hospital's Rule once, and note that we want the limit of $\frac{a+be^{bx}}{2x}$ to be $1$.

Comment: Then L'Hospital's Rule it is. We do get that $a=-b$. The limit of $(a+be^{bx})/(2x)$ is then $b^2/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hopital's Rule, we get that $$\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{ax-1+e^{bx}}{x^2}\right) = \lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{a+be^{bx}}{2x}\right)$$

For the limit on the right hand side to not go to $\infty$, we need to let $a + b e^{bx} = 0$ when $x = 0$. This makes $a + b = 0$, and indeed $a = -b$.

Taking the L'Hopital's again, we get $$\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{a+be^{bx}}{2x}\right) = \lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{b^2e^{bx}}{2}\right)$$

For the value on the right hand side to equal $1$ at $x = 0$, we need $b^2 = 2$, or $b = \pm\sqrt{2}$. Substituting back to $a = -b$, we get $a = \mp\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the apprximation for $ x \sim 0 $

> $$e^{bx} \sim 1+bx +\frac{b^2 x^2}{2!} .$$